# Is it possible to define a global dependency for all rake tasks in a given namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

If I know that in the namespace `:foo` every of my rake tasks will have `:environment` as a dependency, is there a way to declare this once globally instead of adding `=> :environment` after the name of every tasks? This doesn't work:

```
namespace foo: :environment do
  task :bar

  task :baz
end
```